# modify ancestorId on clicknium python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to modify `ancestorId` on `clicknium` Python library. Please see the red box in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hljzC.png). I want to check the checkboxes that meet certain conditions, and `ancestorId` distinguishes the checkboxes.

Somebody suggested the following solutions using `clicknium` and a locator package:

```py
from clicknium import clicknium as cc, locator

# Capture the locator of the checkbox using Clicknium Recorder
checkbox_locator = locator.new_store.sample.checkbox

# Modify the ancestorId value in the locator
modified_locator = checkbox_locator.replace(ancestorId="new_ancestor_id")
```

However, I couldn't find the `replace` function in the library. I've been struggling with this problem for the past four days.

Comment: Clicknium has their own support forum, have you tried asking there?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the red box in the locator page can be edited directly

Comment: I've solved it! I can change via xpath thank you :)